# Supporting Authentication for HTML files in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have web application developed in `ASP.Net` MVC, hosted in `IIS`.  Client has provided set of `HTML` files for Help.  We have provided link to those `HTML` files in our application.  Those `HTML` files are stored in a folder within web-directory of hosted applications.  Expectation is that `HTML` pages should not be accessed by any unauthorized users.  As they are static pages and if we know URL, we can directly access by providing address in address-bar.  Please suggest how to overcome?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with PDFs ( not HTML) to resolve did so :

```
public class MyFileController : Controller
{   
    [AccessControl]
    public FileResult Pdf()
    {
        return File(@"filepath\file.pdf", "System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf");
    }
}
```

try with `System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html`

Comment: This may help for first file.  But, subsequent hits are also through HTML.  How will they be authenticated?

Comment: You can not leave the files in a location with direct access.
Accept only access through the action.
The action may have a filename parameter.
And access control I did using an attribute (AccessControlAttribute).